# How to import XAML pages together with code-behind in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to port my Windows 8 Store application from Developer Preview to RTM now and I got problems with importing old XAML layout into the newly created project (the old project isn't runnable anymore).

Whenever I import .xaml and .xaml.cs files, they are not recognized as a single file. Rather, two different files are added. How can I import both files as a single "entity", as it happens if I add a new XAML page to my project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When including XAML files you should have both XAML and xaml.cs files in the same folder, and then in Visual Studio select for including only the XAML files, not the xaml.cs files - they should be included automatically in the process.

Answer (score 6):

Corresponding `.cs` or `.vb` files are imported on import of `.xaml` files,
but in **VS2012** there is one catch:

[image]    you must import **only one XAML file at a time**

**If you mark more than one file in file selector**, XAML files are not paired correctly with their corresponding code files (even in case if you switch filter to **All Files** and then select both XAML and code files).

Comment: Yes, only one at a time also in VS2015 RC. Can you beleave it?

Comment: Also true for VS 2017.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2015: To add an existing XAMLs with its corresponding code-behind, just copy all the files (.xaml and .vb) via File Explorer and Paste in VS' Solution Explorer.